# spring-kafka-test in SSL

Tags: spring, spring-kafka

Hi I´m trying to use `spring-kafka-test` to test an embedded `kafka` in my test.

I´m not able to find the project in Github spring repos.

Also I would like to know if the embedded kafka of the library can work not only in `PLAIN_TEXT` but also in `SSL` protocol.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

To start an Embeddedkafka you can annotate your Test class with this

`@EnableKafka
@EmbeddedKafka(partitions = 1, controlledShutdown = true, topics = {"topic1","topic2"})
public class myTest {
}`

Also you would get the kafka and zookeeper address via 
In your test you can connect using following commands

`System.getProperty("spring.embedded.kafka.brokers")
System.getProperty("spring.embedded.zookeeper.connect")`

For SSL, I dont have done that but would be curious to find the answer.

Comment: The embedded kafka broker does not support SSL - why do you need it - it's intended for testing only.